# Getting revlant content from a url with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mechanize

I have this class

```
class Scrapper
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'mechanize'

    def initialize(url)
        @url = url
        agent = Mechanize.new
        @page = agent.get(url)
    end

    def perform(type)
        if type == 'title'
            get_title
        else
            get_content
        end
    end

    def get_title
        @page.title
    end

    def get_content
        @page
    end
end
```

Right now i can get the title of the page but how do i get the relevant content? 
E.g. http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2014/03/06/facebook-launches-improved-version-major-news-feed-redesign-teased-last-year/#!yJE5N

- I would like to get a cover/any relevant image if any.
- The content of the page.

   
  Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of relevant seems relevant here... Take a look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) which mechanize was built on.

Comment: Relevnant image, for example, the cover image for that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return that image as a `Nokogiri::XML::Element`

```
def get_article_image_tag
  @page.at(".article-featured-image > img")
end
#=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x19ac280 name="img" attributes= #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac238 name="width" value="786">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac22c name="height" value="305">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac 220 name="src" value="http://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/03 187265573-786x305.jpg">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac214 name="class" value="attachment-featured_post wp-post-image">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac208 name="alt" value="SWEDEN-FACEBOOK-DATA-CENTER-SERVERS">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x19ac1fc name="title" value="Facebook launches an improved version of the News Feed redesign teased last year">]>
```

This will return the source url

```
def get_article_image_src
  @page.at(".article-featured-image > img").attributes["src"].value
end
#=>"http://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/03/187265573-786x305.jpg"
```

To get the article text

```
def get_article_text
  @page.at("div.article").text
end
```

This will return the article text without any formatting just text and non visible characters such as `\n`, `\t`, etc. This method also seems to scrape HTML/Javascript code inside the selector.

Also for dynamic capabilities you could alter your call here

```
def perform(type)
   self.send("get_#{type.to_s}")
end
```

then it can be called with any of "content", "title","article_image_tag","article_image_src" and any other get_xxx methods you define.

**Edit** to show your user all the images this will work in rails view

```
<% @page.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image.url) %>
<% end %>
```

This will iterate through all the images and display them in image tags in your page. Obviously this may need tinkering depending on if the urls are relative or full.

Honestly unless you need `mechanize` to set cookies or something I would take a look at `Nokogiri`. Not 100% sure how to do this with mechanize but with `Nokogiri` you could determine "relevance" of a picture by it's overall size like so.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2014/03/06/facebook-launches-improved-version-major-news-feed-redesign-teased-last-year/#!yJ6uM"))
largest_image = doc.search("img").sort_by{|image| image.attributes["height"].value.to_i * image.attributes["width"].value.to_i}.pop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping but what if if was another url? I'm trying to add this to my site by making the user enter the url and it returns an image + the text content.

Comment: Ohhh yhh. That is exactly what i want. I'll try Nokogiri out and get back to yu. Thankksss :)